# SCP command keeps asking password

Tags: linux, ssh, scp, authorization

I've been struggling for days with this now and can't find what I'm doing wrong.

I've got a website on a VPS server. Every night I make a backup of the database. It gets stored on my VPS server. I also want to send a copy to my NAS (Synology DS214play) at home. Both servers operate on Linux.

So I've logged into my VPS server (as root) and generated a `ssh-keygen`.

On my VPS it looks like this:

```
[root@vps /]# cd ~
[root@vps ~]# ls -alh
dr-xr-x---.  7 root root 4.0K Jun 25 18:58 .
dr-xr-xr-x. 24 root root 4.0K Jun 25 19:33 ..
drwx------   3 root root 4.0K Jun 25 20:29 .ssh
[root@vps ~]# cd .ssh
[root@vps .ssh]# ls -alh
drwx------  3 root root 4.0K Jun 25 20:29 .
dr-xr-x---. 7 root root 4.0K Jun 25 18:58 ..
-rw-------  1 root root 1.7K Jun 26 07:27 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  403 Jun 26 07:27 id_rsa.pub
-rw-------  1 root root  394 Jun 25 20:29 known_hosts
```

Then I copied the file to the NAS by using `ssh-copy-id`

```
admin@NAS:/$ cd ~
admin@NAS:~$ ls -alh
drwxrwxrwx  6 admin users 4.0K Jun 26 07:28 .
drwxrwxrwx 13 root  root  4.0K Jun 21 20:57 ..
drwx------  2 admin users 4.0K Jun 26 07:28 .ssh
admin@NAS:~$ cd .ssh
admin@NAS:~/.ssh$ ls -alh
drwx------ 2 admin users 4.0K Jun 26 07:28 .
drwxrwxrwx 6 admin users 4.0K Jun 26 07:28 ..
-rw------- 1 admin users  403 Jun 26 07:27 authorized_keys
```

When looking into `VPS/id_rsa.pub` and `NAS/authorized_keys` I see that both keys are identical.

Now I'm trying to copy a test file from the VPS to the NAS by using:

```
[root@vps /]# scp -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa /test.txt admin@___.___.___.___:/volume1/SQL_backup
```

That however results in shell asking me for the password (every time).

How come that I have to keep giving my pass?

Comment: What is the exact message/prompt you see when you are asked for a password?  Do you get the same problem if you `ssh` to the NAS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When troubleshooting problems with daemons, you should always check the system logs.
In this particular case, if you check your system logs on the `NAS` host, you'll see something similar to:

```
Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /home/admin
```

The problem is shown in this output:

```
admin@NAS:~$ ls -alh
drwxrwxrwx  6 admin users 4.0K Jun 26 07:28 .
```

For security, SSH will refuse to use the `authorized_keys` file if any ancestor of the `~/.ssh` directory is writable by someone other than the user or root (ancestor meaning `/home/user/.ssh`, `/home/user`, `/home`, `/`). This is because another user could replace the `~/.ssh` directory (or `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file) with their own, and then ssh into your user.

To fix, change the permissions on the directory with something like:

```
chmod 755 ~
```

Comment: well spotted! I see the permission there in the listing.

Comment: parent of ~ should probably also be not-writable,

Comment: correct. Updated answer to be more technically accurate.

Comment: Awesome! It was both AnilV's answer and yours that helped me. I changed the permissions and got away of the -i identifier and got it working. Thanks for the afford guys!

Answer (score 3):

Any chance you created a password for your private key while creating it using `ssh-keygen`.

Following is the workflow I use:

1. `ssh-keygen`
2. `ssh-copy-id root@remote_host`
3. `scp /test.text root@remote_host:/opt/application/`

Comment: By password you mean passphrase? Then no. You don't use the -i option? I'll give it a try when I'm home

Comment: You are right, passphrase.

Comment: Awesome! It was both Patricks answer and yours that helped me. I changed the permissions and got away of the -i identifier and got it working. Thanks for the afford guys!

Comment: @LinkinTED `-i` is optional. Having it won't cause `ssh` to not work.